# C++ priority queue - when to rebalance the heap?

Tags: c++, compare, heap, priority-queue

Checking C++ priority_queue API, the user-provided `Compare` only specified the rules of reordering, but not specified when to reinforce the ordering.

For example, say I am using priority_queue to get the **max occurrence of char in a string**.
Assume the string is `"cab"`,  prioritu_queue has `c, 1` now. And now I want to insert `a,1`, then `b,1` into it :

```
    auto cmp = [&](const char& letter1, const char& letter2) {
        return v[letter1 - 'a'] < v[letter2 - 'a'];
    };
    priority_queue<char, vector<char>, decltype(cmp)> q{cmp};
```

Quoted from [official API doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

> A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.
> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. However, **because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last.** That is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to the weak ordering

Does this mean that the above operation will return `b` to me ( as `b,1` comes last, and all three elements in PQ are equally counted such that a weak ordering)?

And if so, the only way to get `a` ( alphabetic order) will be that I re-write `cmp` to enforce it consider alphabetic order, in addition to char occurrence count?

PS, I do have tried to experiment myself: https://onlinegdb.com/YDjOcABJh
This is the code I use to test if `b` comes or `c` comes first, the experiment result is `c`, not `b`!

I am confused on the API wording now, any help is appreciated!

Thanks!